# Sort Div id by using Php (or by java)

Tags: php, sorting, html

Is there a fairly easy way to sort div id's with php?
I tried a jquery script to sort it be it gave a big delay on the page load.

Example html part (unsorted)

```
<div id="1">Content1</div>
<div id="3">Content3</div>
<div id="2">Content2</div>
```

Example html part (End result, Sorted with php or java)

```
<div id="1">Content1</div>
<div id="2">Content2</div>
<div id="3">Content3</div>
```

Thank you,
Bjorn

Comment: How is the html generated? is it just an static file?

Comment: The html is not generated. But the id is generated by php file. It will give me a result with 0 or 1 or 3 etc. So I want all the 0's to come first and then the 1 and so  on.

Comment: Or it could also just read the text from a div. Like <span>text (123 in my case)</span>

Comment: @Bul I'm afraid I didn't get it. Why are you generating id's in the first the place? Usually you go from id to content, not the other way around :p Can you give an example on what the data looks like in the first place (before manipulating it with PHP) and what transformations are then done?

Comment: Sorry. Here is an example how the id ends up in the div. <div id="<?php
$status= file_get_contents('output.php?output=content3321);
echo $status
?>"></div>

Comment: So the answer from the php will be "0" or "1" or simular.

Answer (score 1):

You can, using the [DOM extension](http://php.net/dom). See [DOMNode::insertBefore](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php) and [DOMNode::removeChild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php).

However, you should ask yourself why they're unsorted in the first place.

Do they come from a database? In that case you can sort the query.
They come from some place else? Try to to reorder the data before building the HTML markup.

Comment: Those are good questions and a great way of approaching programming problems in the first place

Comment: The result comes back as text from a php file. Let's say I run result.php?id=content321 and it will give me back the reply "0" or "1"
These replys are set into the div or anywhere else I wanna have them.